Debian 12: Particular VM no longer boots properly
When one of our VMs rebooted yesterday it refused to come back up in a strange way.
An overview of the VM:

Debian 12 on a VMWare ESXi instance.
/dev/sda is a virtual disk with 3 GPT partitions (exists on a RAID host) consisting of:

/dev/sda1: EFI boot with UUID 7FAD-A6AB.
/dev/sda2: Main boot with UUID 647d1330-ecfd-49f2-b83e-d93a57877997.
/dev/sda3: Crypt "sda3_crypt" with UUID cdea6a76-3073-4db1-a1d9-649af4b6324a, containing an LVM with volume group "nexus-backup".

/dev/mapper/nexus--backup-root: Root filesystem (EXT4).
/dev/mapper/nexus--backup-var: "/var" filesystem (EXT4).




/dev/sdb is a virtual disk for swap purposes only (exists on a lone SSD).

/dev/sdb1: Crypt "sdb1_crypt" with UUID dfea69be-3e5d-4cca-b439-603aedad9498, swap partition.



When booting I'm asked for my LUKS passwords, accepts fine, then the boot progress begins as normal. It seems to them time out waiting for block storage devices to start. Some of the UUIDs from above are shown. This waits for 90 seconds then aborts, tries to continue, but eventually just hangs forever as something has failed to load. The recovery mode boot shows various services starting up just fine. I do not get the familiar rescue prompt (the one asking for root password or pressing Control+D). It may be possible that LVM is not starting up properly, though I've not seen an error message for it.
I'm not currently convinced that the issue is boot/initramfs related though. The boot process gets far enough in to read and apply network interface configurations from /etc/network/interface.d, and is pingable, but doesn't get far enough to present a console TTY or start an SSH daemon. (CTRL+F1 through to CTRL+F6 do not provide a TTY.)
I can get into a live or rescue environment and chroot into the system just fine, in that the file system is fully usable, so I don't think anything significant is corrupt or irreparable. Once inside I've tried:

Triple check the contents (UUIDs in particular) are right in both /etc/crypttab and /etc/fstab.
update-initramfs -u -k all
update-grub
Reconfigure grub (via dpkg-reconfigure).
fsck, with a forced check, no corruption revealed.
Trying to boot with various entries commented out from /etc/fstab so the boot process should not hang around for them (with a update-initramfs -u -k all after).

I've captured 2 short recordings of the boot process:

Regular boot: Gets interesting at 2:02.
Recovery boot: Gets interesting at 0:27, more interesting at 01:57.

Contents of /etc/crypttab:
# <target name> <source device>         <key file>      <options>
sda3_crypt      UUID=cdea6a76-3073-4db1-a1d9-649af4b6324a       none    luks
sdb1_crypt      UUID=dfea69be-3e5d-4cca-b439-603aedad9498       none    luks,swap

Contents of /etc/fstab:
# <file system>                                 <mount point>   <type>          <options>                       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/nexus--backup-root                  /               ext4            acl,errors=remount-ro           0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=647d1330-ecfd-49f2-b83e-d93a57877997       /boot           ext4            defaults                        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=7FAD-A6AB                                  /boot/efi       vfat            umask=0077                      0       1
/dev/mapper/nexus--backup-var                   /var            ext4            acl,defaults                    0       2
/dev/mapper/sdb1_crypt                          none            swap            sw                              0       0

Would anyone here have any insight as to what may have gone wrong? (in b4 total reinstall)
Thanks :)

just as generic, have you checked the filesystems for errors? has an update occurred?

Yes, I was able to use fsck on all file systems from a live rescue system -- no errors.
The last major update was well over a week ago, it had been running fine since that.

open a support case on VMware I mean for what other reason you pay for it ;)

I don't think this is quite a VMWare issue. :P 3 other VMs on the same host run perfectly fine.

don't think, I mean the support of the them is usually included...

A few good folks at Debian's Sub-Reddit kindly steered me towards the cause of the problem. It appears that the boot process is not properly mounting LVM volumes. This is causing the "/var" filesystem not to mount, which would explain the torrent of failure to start up various services.
The trick here was to hide away "/etc/fstab" by using a live Debian instance, reboot into a recovery mode, and as the boot process fails with no volumes to mount it presented a rescue shell. Logging in as root I can put this back, reloaded it, ensure LVM volumes are activated, mount everything, then exit the rescue shell to continue as normal.
Basic steps:

Boot into a separate live system.
Mount the fixed system's volumes. (cryptsetup luksOpen, lvscan, then mount)
Optionally chroot into your fixed system's root filesystem, otherwise prepend the mount path to the next line:
mv "/etc/fstab" "/etc/fstab.disabled-tmp"
Unmount the fixed system's volumes. (sync, umount, lvchange -an, cryptsetup luksClose)
Reboot into a recovery mode option. (A standard option won't provide the rescue shell.)
Wait for the rescue shell, enter root password.
lvscan
mount -o remount,rw /
mv "/etc/fstab.disabled-tmp" "/etc/fstab"
systemctl daemon-reload
mount -a
exit
System continues to boot and functions normally.

At this point I could double check that all disks were mounted correctly, rebuild the initramfs, and reboot.
As a precaution I also deployed an additional initramfs script to ensure that LVM volume groups are activated during the boot sequence. (Be sure to update-initramfs -u -k all after adding that.)
